# Dynamically altering a filepath in Excel on sharepoint when using filter

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I Currently have the below formula

`=FILTER('filepath[workbookname.xlsx]January'!$E:$E,(D4=''filepath[workbookname.xlsx]January'!$E:$EJanuary'!$A:$A)*("New Business"='filepath[workbookname.xlsx]January'!$H:$H))`

What I am trying to do (after trying multiple alternatives) is have the sheet name (January) be dynamic. I have a dropdown in D5 which lists the months, and these are exactly the same as the sheet names in the workbook I'm linking to on SharePoint (both file are on SharePoint). I want to replace January with the value in D5

I  cannot use Indirect as this would require both sheets to be open, as this wouldn't be the case.

I'm sure I am missing something obvious but just cannot get it to play nice? Help

Tried Indirect but this doesn't work as the file isn't open, tried using hyperlink/concatenate but it doesn't seem to work when just adjusting the sheet name